# Clients not receiving data from Server python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, client-server, python-sockets

I am new to  Python. I am writing a Server program and a Client program. In here, Server plays the role of distributing the data to the multiple clients. It works great. My task is to distribute the data from the server by using server.py file. Whenever any clients wants it, he just execute clients.py in his laptop and get the results. But in here, the Server starts distributing the data. The ip, the server using was 127.0.1.1. It is not taking the network provided ip. How to make it use the ip provided by LAN. When the clients from other computer execute clients.py file . It shows Connection refused error. Note that we are all connected in the LAN. How to solve it and make clients receive the data.

Here's the sample Client Code:

```
import socket
import os
from threading import Thread


import socket
import time

s = socket.socket()  
host = '127.0.1.1'  
port = 10016
print(host)


s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    print(s.recv(1024))
s.close()
```

Sample Server Code:

```
import socket
import os
from threading import Thread
import thread
import threading
import time
import datetime

def listener(client, address):
    print ("Accepted connection from: ", address)
    with clients_lock:
        clients.add(client)
    try:    
        while True: 
            client.send(a)
            time.sleep(2)   

    finally:
        with clients_lock:
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()

clients = set()
clients_lock = threading.Lock()

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 10016

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(3)
th = []
print ("Server is listening for connections...")
while True:
    client, address = s.accept()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b %d %Y,%a, %I:%M:%S %p")
    a = "Hi Steven!!!" + timestamp
    th.append(Thread(target=listener, args = (client,address)).start())
s.close()
```

Comment: Use the host address of `0.0.0.0` on the server.

Comment: No.. It still shows Connection refused error on Client  side

Comment: Have You tried to use `127.0.1.1` instead of `seocket.gethostname`?

Comment: Yes..i tried 127.0.1.1

Comment: the clients py file is working only on server computer where the server.py file is executing. how to make it work on other computers on lan

Comment: IIRC, you use `socket.bind(("", port))` for the server side. Note empty string for the host. Then for the client, you use `socket.connect((host_or_ip, port))` where `host_or_ip` is NOT `127.0.0.1` as on the client machine, `127.0.0.1` would refer to his own machine.

Comment: It doesn't work...i tried using empty string on host. Still on client side, it shows error

Comment: Of cause the clients will also have to connect to the outside IP of the server. 127.* addresses are used on the internal loopback interface only, not in the LAN.

Comment: then how can share this data over lan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer

In the '/etc/hosts' file content, i have an IP address mapping with '127.0.1.1' to my hostname. This is causing the name resolution to get 127.0.1.1. I commented this line. Now it works. Every one in my lan can receive the data

Server Code:

```
import socket
import os
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time
import datetime

def listener(client, address):
    print ("Accepted connection from: ", address)
    with clients_lock:
        clients.add(client)
    try:    
        while True: 
            client.send(a)
            time.sleep(2)   

    finally:
        with clients_lock:
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()

clients = set()
clients_lock = threading.Lock()

host = socket.getfqdn()  # it gets ip of lan
port = 10016

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(3)
th = []
print ("Server is listening for connections...")
while True:
    client, address = s.accept()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%b %d %Y,%a, %I:%M:%S %p")
    a = ("Hi Steven!!!" + timestamp).encode()
    th.append(Thread(target=listener, args = (client,address)).start())
s.close()
```

Client Code:

```
import socket
import os
import time

s = socket.socket()  
host = '192.168.1.43' #my server ip 
port = 10016
print(host)
print(port)

s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    print((s.recv(1024)).decode())
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

configure the ip provided by LAN to client.py (ip in LAN like this: 192.168.122.33)

```
host = 'ip provided by LAN'
```

Comment: No. it's not connecting. Still shows connection error. My data was running on the server ip.

Comment: is it possible that your client cant't access the server on the lan？is the firewall closed?

Comment: you can have try this in shell: telnet ipinlan 10016

Comment: telnet: could not resolve ipinlan/10016: Name or service not known error

Comment: and the firewall status was inactive